# How can I recognize a romanized word after learning the Korean Alphabet?

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-korean

I know how to write and pronounce the Korean Alphabet (Hangul). However, whenever I want to type/say something, I have to be aware that some words are romanized or changed into something else. For example; “안녕하세요”/Annyeonghaseyo means “Hello” in English. “Annyeonghaseyo” is a romanization word for ‘Hello’ and it’s not the actual Hangul letters, as one would think. If I was a complete newbie, I’d think “Hello” would be written as “헤로” (ㅎ  ㅔ ㄹ  ㅗ  which spells out the word H-E-L-L-O). In Korean, 헤로 means Hero, if I’m not wrong.

Anyways, to get to the point; how can I recognize a romanized word after learning the Korean Alphabet? Or what’s the next step after learning Hangul?

Comment: what kind of words are you talking about? Are you saying 안녕하세요 is not written as such and is changed into something else?

Comment: this is well know and hard to recognize problem. Currently, there is no clear cut rule to detect koreanized english word